# Django wsgi.py change monitor detecting changes when none have been made

Tags: python, django

I'm developing django based site on a windows machine, but I git push my changes to a headless Ubuntu server for staging purposes. When I git pull the changes into the working directory on the staging server I then need to run manage.py collectstatic.  However, when I do this the change monitor ('Monitoring Code Changes' section of [Reloading Source Code](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode)) reports that it has detected changed files:

```
monitor (pid=26216): Starting change monitor.

You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings.

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: monitor (pid=26216): Change detected to 'myproject/manage.py'.
monitor (pid=26216): Triggering process restart.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/envs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/envs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/envs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 222, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/envs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 255, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/envs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 385, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/envs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 160, in handle_noargs
    % (destination_display, clear_display))
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I ran 'touch myproject/wsgi.py' to 'update the change cache' and then ran the collectstatic command again.  This resulted in the same error.

I then entered the python console and ran the monitor starting command manually:

```
import myproject.monitor
myproject.monitor.start(1)
```

This made no difference. I also tried adding a conditional to the monitor so that it would ignore manage.py when checking for file changes but this just gave me the same error with myproject/__init__.py being the file it reported as having changed. DOes anyone know what is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked out what was causing this. The legacy file modification times are held in a dictionary as unix timestamps with decimal places (e.g. 1366283624.92) while the actual modification times are returned by `os.stat(path).st_mtime` as integers.  All I had to do was edit the monitor script at line 54, changing:

```
if mtime != _times[path]:
```

to

```
if int(mtime) != int(_times[path]):
```

I just hope this doesn't lead to any further problems down the road